# Made a slot machine game but I can't find a way to save the money that's made

Tags: python

```
#Slot machine
import random
import time
def main():
    
    Money = 100 **<-- this is the problem**
    SlotMachine = ["Strawberry", "Apple", "Banana"]
    Slot1 = []
    Slot2 = []
    Slot3 = []
    
    while True:
        if Money > 0:
            print("If you lose, you'll lose all the money you put on the line. But if you win your money gets trippled!")
            MoneyOnTheLine = int(input("How much money would you like to put on the table? "))
            if MoneyOnTheLine < 0:
                continue
            if MoneyOnTheLine > Money:
                print("You don't have that kind of money...")
                continue
            Money = Money - MoneyOnTheLine
            Roll()
            if Slot1 == Slot2 == Slot3:
                print("You win!")
                WinnersMoney = MoneyOnTheLine * 3
                print(f"You received", WinnersMoney, "!")
                Money = Money + WinnersMoney
                print(f"You have", Money, "now!")
                Restart = input("Good job, you won! Wanna play again? (Yes/No) ").lower()
                if Restart == "yes":
                    main()
                else:
                    print("I'll see you another time, friend!")
                    quit()
            else:
                print(f"You have", Money, "now!")
                Restart = input("It seems you lost wanna play again? (Yes/No) ").lower()
                if Restart == "yes":
                    main()
                else:
                    print("I'll see you another time, friend!")
                    quit()
        else:
            print("You are poor!")
            quit()
main()
```

I tried in the start by placing the starter money out of the main loop but that's not possible and I can't find a way for it to save now. Had to cut a part of the code out but it's the parts that I think don't matter for this problem I'm having.

Comment: `Money = 100` creates a new local variable on each recursive call. You can either make it a `global` variable, or pass it as a parameter. For example: `def main(Money=100):` then recursively call it like `main(Money)`.

Comment: Optionally instead of recursively calling main() you could just run this logic in a while loop so you don't lose variable scope through your iterations.